# How to get data from subCollection document, firestore(Flutter)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a data Collection in firebase.
It has user data documents and each document contains a collection called GPA.
In GPA collection there are 8 documents and I want to get data from one of that document called sem1
this is my getData function. But it not work
Please give me a solution for this.

```
_getData() async {
    {
      var docID;
      var firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
      final databaseReference = Firestore.instance;
      databaseReference
          .collection("users")
          .where('uid', isEqualTo: firebaseUser.uid)
          .getDocuments()
          .then((querySnapshot) {
        docID = querySnapshot.documents[0].reference.documentID;
      });

      var query = databaseReference
          .collection('users')
          .document(docID)
          .collection('GPA')
          .document(sem1)
          .get()
          .then((DocumentSnapshot ds) {
        print(ds.data);
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are that you trying to use `docID` before it is populated, since `getDocuments()` is an async call, so you either would have to `await` to populate `docId` or do everything inside `getDocuments().then()`. I would recommend the latter, and it could look like this:

```
_getData() async {
    var docID;
    var query;
    var firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    final databaseReference = Firestore.instance;
    databaseReference
        .collection("users")
        .where('uid', isEqualTo: firebaseUser.uid)
        .getDocuments()
        .then((querySnapshot) {
            docID = querySnapshot.documents[0].reference.documentID;
            query = databaseReference
                        .collection('users')
                        .document(docID)
                        .collection('GPA')
                        .document(sem1)
                        .get()
                        .then((DocumentSnapshot ds) {
                            print(ds.data);
                        });
        });
}
```